# Input range slider left side different colour than the right side of the slider in React with ref.current.style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

I've been trying to set input[type='range'] overflow to hidden, however because input[type='range'] overflow set to hidden it's not possible to make a thumb a few px bigger so am trying to implement some logic within a component itself instead with no luck.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lewin-c3ru1?file=/src/styles.css:825-1328)

**js:**

```
const Slide3 = (props) => {


  const slider = useRef();

  const min = slider.min;
  const max = slider.max;
  const value = slider.value;

  if (slider.current) {
    // loaded
    slider.current.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red ${
      ((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100
    }%, #DEE2E6 ${((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100}%, #DEE2E6 100%)`;

    slider.current.oninput = function () {
      slider.current.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red ${
        ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * 100
      }%, #DEE2E6 ${
        ((this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)) * 100
      }%, #DEE2E6 100%)`;
    };
  }

  return (
    <div className="slide-3">
      <div className="sliders-container">
        {' '}
        <Slider
          name="Thickness"
          id="thickness-slider"
          min={0.01}
          max={0.1}
          step={0.01}
          refs={slider}
        />
        <Slider name="Length" id="length-slider" min={120} max={150} step={1} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**css:**

```
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  /*30x30px adjusted to be same as 28x28px on moz*/
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

You can check out this tool: https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler
It generates CSS with a bit of javascript to style `<input>` range sliders, with progress indication among other things.

Here is an example:

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"].slider-progress')) {
  e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value);
  e.style.setProperty('--min', e.min == '' ? '0' : e.min);
  e.style.setProperty('--max', e.max == '' ? '100' : e.max);
  e.addEventListener('input', () => e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value));
}
```

```css
/*generated with Input range slider CSS style generator (version 20201223)
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler*/
input[type=range].styled-slider {
  height: 2.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*progress support*/
input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress {
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * 2em + var(--ratio) * (100% - 2em));
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*webkit*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: calc(max((1em - 1px - 1px) * 0.5,0px) - 2em * 0.5);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
}
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#007cf8,#007cf8) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #efefef;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#0061c3,#0061c3) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #e5e5e5;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#2f98f9,#2f98f9) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #f5f5f5;
}

/*mozilla*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-track {
  height: max(calc(1em - 1px - 1px),0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#007cf8,#007cf8) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #efefef;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#0061c3,#0061c3) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #e5e5e5;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#2f98f9,#2f98f9) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #f5f5f5;
}

/*ms*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-ms-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-ms-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: max(calc(1em - 1px - 1px),0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #0061c3;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2f98f9;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" style="width: 600px;" />
```